# Add access point without ethernet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a TP-Link wireless access point that I would like to set up so I can access WiFi at both ends of the building. The issue is I don't want to have an ethernet cable running across the floor.

Is there a way for me to set up a second access point that connects to the router wirelessly instead of through an ethernet cable? I'd even be willing to purchase a new Access Point if there is a brand out there that does offer this functionality(assuming the TP-Link doesn't). I realize that doing it this way will reduce my available bandwidth but it's worth it if I can avoid stringing an ethernet cable through multiple rooms.

*Note: I'm looking to set it up as an Access Point, **NOT a Repeater**. I tried setting it up as a Repeater and some devices connect to the weaker signal or will randomly disconnect.*

Comment: These are called wireless extenders.

Comment: They're also called wifi range extenders. Google them and you'll find many products.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you are really looking for are access points that function as a [mesh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11s) wireless network (or [a non-802.11 specific article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_mesh_network)).

Typically in a mesh network the access points are dual-band or have two radios.  One of the radios/frequencies is used to provide the "backhaul" or the uplink between the two access points.  The second radio is configured to provide service to client devices.

You don't specify the type of building/structure, so another option that may be worth considering is to use something like [power line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication) or [Ethernet over coax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_coax) adapters to utilize existing wiring in the building to extend the wired network to the location of the second access point.

Comment: I used to use homeplug AV (A common flavour of poweline networking) and its reasonably reliable. Just remember that big motors like washing machines can cause connection disconnects and sometimes moving a plug will have dramatic effects on reliability. Also, get the passthrough type adaptors since they filter noise from whatever's plugged in, and they let you actually use that socket for power.

Answer (score 1):

### Requirements

- 1 2.4GHZ compatible Wireless Card to connect to internet source (a router)
- 2nd 5GHZ(2.4 will work but this is better imo) band compatible Wireless Card to be Access Point

or

Dual Band "300/600 mbps" Card

(Not a repeater because it uses NAT and assigns a subnet)

1. Connect to Internet via main card on typical 2.4 GHZ band
2. Set AP mode on second card (TP Link has a built in one. Theres a "SoftAP mode"

Some WiFi chips have a HARDWARE AP switch (mediatek does) easier to work with.
If this is the case, then turn alt card to AP mode - and Just bridge Cards A + B

See "Create Accesspoint in Windows 7/8/10" for the powershell HOW-Tos

Answer (score -1):

**By definition**, you are trying to set up a repeater. The only thing that differentiates it from an access point is that its uplink is also coming from a wireless signal instead of Ethernet.

You can still name the repeated network with a different name than the primary one. This should prevent the issue of connecting to the weaker network by accident (although wireless cards are *supposed* to always choose the stronger connection).

The strategy I would follow to make this work the best would be to use devices that will allow you to have *directional* antennas. You can even make one yourself [out of cardboard](http://www.freeantennas.com/projects/template/). Even better if your access points have multiple antennas, so you can allocate one on each device for what would effectively be a "line of sight" connection between the two devices that will be able to make it through the walls of your building in a way that the other omnidirectional antennas won't. The omni antennas would then provide reception to your devices in each space.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you could assign a different name to a repeater. I'll try this out.

Comment: This is incorrect.  [Repeaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater) by definition simply repeat or regenerate a signal.  This is not what the original poster asked about.